# Bluetooth pairing issue with dual boot

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, sound, bluetooth, headphones

I have dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 with windows 10. I have Bose QC35-II headphones. The problem is, if I pair my headphones with Windows, when I switch to Ubuntu, it does not pair automatically. I have to delete the device and then add it again. Similarly, if I pair it with ubuntu and then switch to windows, I have to delete the device and then add it again as a new Bluetooth device. What could be done to solve this?
I have an Asus GU502L - Intel i7, Nvidia 1660Ti.

Comment: This is about the headphones, not the computer. check out [this article from Bose](https://www.bose.com/en_us/support/articles/HC1283/productCodes/qc35_ii/article.html.html.html.html) on how to switch which device the headphones are connected to without disconnecting/reconnecting.

Comment: For dumber bt devices, you can edit the linkkeys to be the same on Ubuntu (/var/lib/bluetooth/<hostMAC>/<deviceMAC>/info) and buried in the windows registery. Pair on one OS, then bring the key to the other.

Answer (score 1):

here's an easy solution, change mac address of bluetooth on linux then pair with your bluetooth device and it will work as expected. however you need to change mac address on every boot.

https://superuser.com/a/1779123/600836

> There's a quite easy solution for this problem. the problem is:
> Windows pairs with this bluetooth device as it's the manager of the
> internal bluetooth module of your laptop, however linux thinks so too.
>
> They both have different pairing signagures.
>
> an easy solution for this, change bluetooth mac address on linux

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
sudo bluemoon -A
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

> now you have a new identity on linux. pair with your device, note you
> have to do this on every restart when you return to windows you won't
> have to repair again.